# US Map in Shiny App does not change with option

Tags: r, shiny, usmap

I am trying to make this shiny app where I want to show the Average Passing Yards per Season of all NFL players in that state.

```
football <- read_csv("Football.csv")

inputPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "var",
                  label = "Variable",
                  choices = c("Passes Attempted" = "Passes Attempted", 
                              "Passes Completed" = "Passes Completed", 
                              "Completion Percentage" = "Completion Percentage", 
                              "Pass Attempts Per Game" = "Pass Attempts Per Game", 
                              "TD Passes" = "TD Passes"),
                  selected = "Completion Percentage")
)

renderPlot({
    Data1 = football%>%
    filter(`Passing Yards` > 100)%>%
    separate(`Birth Place`, into = c("Birth City","state"),sep = ", ",na.rm = TRUE) %>%
      group_by(state) %>%
      summarise(Avg = mean(input$var))

  Data1 = Data1[complete.cases(Data1), ]

  plot_usmap(data = Data1, values = "Avg", color = "white") + 
    scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "A",
       name = "Average Passing Yards Per Season", label = scales::comma
    ) + theme(legend.position = "right")
})
```

But when I try and do this, it does not work and gives me an error saying,

```
Warning in mean.default(input$var) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Comment: The warning message tells you what's going wrong: you're taking the mean of `input$var` but your input is returning you a character. Each of your input choices are character eg. 'Passes Attempted' - perhaps you're expecting input to return the variable `Passes Attempted` but it's just going to return the name

Comment: what you probably want is something like `summarise(Avg = mean(!!ensym(input$var)))`